# Nodejs Two requests are getting fired at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why is my NodeJS app firing two `requests` every time? I am not sure why this OPTIONS is getting fired each and every time, when i am actually only calling the HTTP Methods => `[GET, POST, PUT, DELETE]`

```
OPTIONS /api/v1/admin/user/55e1d606803478cc1edacfa0 200 0.149 ms - -
DELETE /api/v1/admin/user/55e1d606803478cc1edacfa0 200 7.598 ms - 58
```

Below is my code where i am calling OPTIONS.

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key");

    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }

});
```

Because of this two `users` are getting deleted at the same time.

Comment: Have you checked if the browser is requesting favicon.ico?

Answer (score 4):

> Why is my NodeJS app firing two requests every time?

It isn't; the browser is.

> I am not sure why this OPTIONS is getting fired each and every time, when i am actually only calling the HTTP Methods => `[GET, POST, PUT, DELETE]`

Most likely because you're making cross-origin calls, using ajax in a web browser. The `OPTIONS` call is the *preflight* call the browser makes prior to the real call to ensure that the destination server accepts cross-origin calls from a given origin and, if so, to find out what headers, methods, credentials, etc. the server accepts from that origin.

More in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

Not all cross-origin calls require a preflight, but many (possibly most) do; the rules are [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0).